# Strange mount entries, procfs on net:

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, procfs

On a device I get among others the following strange entries for `mount`:

```
none on net:[4026532603] type proc (rw,relatime)
none on net:[4026532424] type proc (rw,relatime)
```

Any idea what or for what this could be? It is the first time I see procfs used for anything but /proc. And what's this "net:"? Something like sockets or pipes?

I am running an 3.8 rt kernel on an embedded device with some form of BusyBox-based Linux

Potentially relevant entries from `/proc/mounts`:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
none net:[4026532603] proc rw,relatime 0 0
none net:[4026532424] proc rw,relatime 0 0
mgmt /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
```

Update:

Thanks to @VenkatC's answer I know now that it has something to do with namespaces, as the following output confirms:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 18:59 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 18:59 mnt -> mnt:[4026532733]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 18:59 net -> net:[4026532603]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 18:59 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 18:59 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

Comment: With what kernel version? What kind of device? Is that a virtualized environment of some kind? Is this a “mainstream” Linux or some other operating system based on a Linux kernel like Android?

Comment: 3.8 rt kernel, an embedded device with some BusyBox-based Linux.

Comment: @phk: do you know if there is anything fancy going on like user-namespaces? Does it also appear in `cat /proc/mounts`?

Comment: @mt_ I edited my post to include the ```/proc/mounts``` output. I will have to do some research on user-namespaces.

Comment: @mt_ Since the introduction of per-process mount namespaces in  2.4.19, /proc/mounts is a symlink to /proc/self/mounts and only shows the mounts of the current pid...

Comment: mount -t proc "none net:[4026532603]" /proc;    mount -t proc "none net:[4026532424]" /proc
Will yield the same result as observed in your /proc/mounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These entries are related to Network namespaces. From man namespaces(7)

```
   The /proc/[pid]/ns/ directory
       Each process has a /proc/[pid]/ns/ subdirectory containing one entry
       for each namespace that supports being manipulated by setns(2):
       $ ls -l /proc/$$/ns
       total 0
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 net -> net:[4026531956]
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 user -> user:[4026531837]
       lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mtk mtk 0 Jan 14 01:20 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

As you see **above net** entry refers to a network namespace. I understand the device in question could be running different process with multiple namespaces

I was able to create a test namespace and see similar mounts in /proc/mounts

```
[cv@cent2 ~]$ ip netns list
netns1
[cv@cent2 ~]$ grep net: /proc/mounts
proc net:[4026532238] proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc net:[4026532238] proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: Network namespaces are used a lot indeed! You might onto something! I will have a look later.

Answer (score 3):

It looks kind of like a dead `nfs` connection.  or maybe `aufs`, maybe even something like a RO rootfs (or liveCD) over nfs with aufs.

Note that when you interpret the numbers (4026532603 and 4026532424) as 32-bit integers and then convert them to IP address format, they are:

```
4026532603 => 240.0.2.72
4026532424 => 240.0.2.251
```

240.0.0.0/4 is "reserved for future use" (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)...so maybe they're used by/for something on the loopback interface. What kind of embedded device is it?

---

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
| Attribute            | Value                |
+----------------------+----------------------+
| Address Block        | 240.0.0.0/4          |
| Name                 | Reserved             |
| RFC                  | [RFC1112], Section 4 |
| Allocation Date      | August 1989          |
| Termination Date     | N/A                  |
| Source               | False                |
| Destination          | False                |
| Forwardable          | False                |
| Global               | False                |
| Reserved-by-Protocol | True                 |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

(link to mentioned [RFC1112, Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1112#section-4))

---

Does `netstat` or `lsof` reveal any connections to/from or anything listening on those IP addresses?

Comment: But what I don't get is why this FS type if it's a NFS share.

Comment: yeah, the `type proc` is a bit of a puzzler.   a bug in your custom kernel perhaps?  maybe even just a cosmetic bug that prints the wrong fstype.

Comment: OK, so there are no open connections according to ```netstat -l``` but according to ```lsof | grep net``` it's opened several times by different processes (including the login shell).

Comment: are you using nfs or aufs for home dirs or something?